# how to fetch SPL by owner without NFT tokens

Tags: spl, fetch, owner

I am using the following code:

```
public async getTokensAccountbyOwner(publicKey: PublicKey) {
const accounts = await this.connection.getParsedProgramAccounts(
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID, // new PublicKey("TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA")
  {
    filters: [
      {
        dataSize: 165, // number of bytes
      },
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 32, // number of bytes
          bytes: publicKey.toBase58(), // base58 encoded string
        },
      },
    ],
  })
  return accounts;
```

}

to fetch SPL owner by wallet, how can i filter out NFTz address?

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to look into the decimals and supply of the Token Mint Account. If the decimals are 0 and the supply is 1 then its an NFT